# How to get Turn By Turn Instruction in HERE SDK

Tags: android, here-api

I'm want to display the turn by turn instruction for navigation like the image

[image]

i had try add LaneInfoListener, but nothing is show
is this feature include in the HERE SDK or need using the data from getNextManeuver()
may i known how can get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the documentation of HERE SDK, the first method should your problem.

From there you need to just manipulate the Route variables/problems(Traffic, stop lights, roundabouts, road issues, etc...) to decide the best action needed to be taken.

Take a look at this

> public static final enumeration Maneuver.Action
>
> Represents values describing the possible actions of a Maneuver.
>
> From: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics_api_nlp/com-here-android-mpa-routing-maneuver.html

Comment: thank you, but you known how can get the direction icon?  i had problem  with the getIcon(), i not able to display it

Answer (score 0):

The SDK com.here.android.routing.Maneuver class provides all the fragments required to construct the instructions. We do not provide the localization to construct the full sentence as that is application specific logic. The icon is for demo only and not provided. Please create some visual assets to map against the maneuver turn type.